# What's missing in this wp_query and meta_query

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

There is something missing because this is driving me crazy at the moment.

I'm using the wp_query with the following args.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'project',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key'       => '_sf_project_budget',
            'value'     => '6',
            //'compare'     => '=',
            //'type'        => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    )       
);
$search_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

When print_r the $search_query I can see the following:

```
WP_Query Object
(
    [query_vars] => Array
        (
            [post_type] => project
            [post_status] => publish
            [meta_query] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => _sf_project_budget
                            [value] => 6
                        )

                )
```

But the "SQL" doesn't seem to change:

```
[request] =>  SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wps_posts.* FROM wps_posts  
WHERE 1=1  AND wps_posts.post_type = 'project' 
AND (wps_posts.post_status = 'publish')  
ORDER BY wps_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Shouldn't this change to incorporate the meta query vars?

Can't see what I'm doing wrong or what's missing, tried different things and it brings all the posts all the time. I checked in postmeta table and I can see that the values are there.

Any pointers in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: why is the 'compare' line commented out? there needs to be a comparison for the meta_query to have any effect

Comment: @spartacus comment or not comment still produces de same result. Also the default value is '='.

Comment: The meta query is converted by [`_get_meta_sql`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-includes/meta.php#L357). You can check the output by hooking into `get_meta_sql`. Dump that value and see what it gives.

Comment: @Jan Fabry, spot on. My problem was coding against the wrong version of wordpress were the meta_query wasn't supported. Update wordpress to the latest version and it worked fine. Totaly my mistake.

Comment: Ah, this can happen to anybody, especially when you work on multiple projects at the same time. I duplicated my comment as an answer so you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meta query is converted by [`_get_meta_sql()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-includes/meta.php#L357). You can check the output by hooking into `get_meta_sql`. Dump that value and see what it gives.